# Defer Plugin Automatic Loading/Opening on Eclipse startup

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I created a new plugin under PDE in eclipse.
Exported it to deployable plugin and pasted it in plugins folder of eclipse.
On Startup of eclipse, the plugins load automatically and come stacked with the console and other windows at the bottom of Eclipse.

I want to defer its automatic load/opening.
I want it to be opened only when I explicitly open it through `Show View>My Plugin`
Following is my plugin.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin autoStart="false">

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="com.Myplugin.packages.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="Myplugin"
            class="com.Myplugin.packages.Perspective"
            id="Myplugin.perspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            name="Myplugin"
            class="com.Myplugin.login.view.OpenView"
            id="Myplugin.view">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="*">
         <view
               closeable="false"
               id="Myplugin.view"
               minimized="false"
               relationship="stack"
               relative="org.eclipse.debug.ui.ModuleView"
               standalone="true"
               visible="true">
         </view>
      </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Perspective.java:

```
 public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        try{
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.setFixed(true);
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
            .addPerspectiveListener(new PerspectiveListener());
        }catch(Exception e){
            OpenView.log4jCallingForError("Perspective error : " +getStackTrace(e));
//          Plugin.getLog().log(new Status(Status.INFO, Activator.PLUGIN_ID, Status.OK, e.getMessage(), e));

        }
    }

    public static String getStackTrace(final Throwable throwable) {
         final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
         final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true);
         throwable.printStackTrace(pw);
         return sw.getBuffer().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Views don't normally open during startup. Show us how you have defined the view in your pligin.xml. Are you doing anything else that would open the view? Note that Eclipse does reopen views that were open the last time you ran the workspace - is this what is happening?

Comment: @greg-449 I am trying it by creating a new workspace. Added Plugin.xml to original post.

Comment: You also need to show us your `Perspective` class

Comment: Added Perspective.java to original post.. Please Note I am using a Perspective Listener as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `visible="true"` in the perspective extensions definition of the view - this makes the view visibile as soon as the perspective is shown. Replace this with `visible="false"`.

Note: You may have to reset the perspective to pick up changes to the perspective definition.

Comment: 1) Set visible = "false"  2) Exported the plugin again to deployable plugin  3) Deleted the old workspace  4) copied the new plugin in plugins folder  5) started eclipse  -- Still plugin is getting loaded on startup

Comment: Specify `-clean` when you start the RCP to make sure the plugin caches are cleared.

Comment: provided -clean tag in eclipse.ini..didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Changing my view properties from

```
<view
               closeable="false"
               id="Myplugin.view"
               minimized="false"
               relationship="stack"
               relative="org.eclipse.debug.ui.ModuleView"
               standalone="true"
               visible="true">
         </view>
```

to this

```
<view
           closeable="true"
           id="Myplugin.view:*"
           minimized="false"
           relationship="stack"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ResourceNavigator"
           standalone="true"
           visible="false">
     </view>
```

worked for me.